# JS: Hashing function for combinable hashes from Objects

Tags: javascript, hash

I need to determine if objects are super/subsets of one another.

Given a function `hash` that generates fixed-length string hashes from arbitrary objects:

```
const fooHash = hash({foo: "foo"}) 
const barHash = hash({bar: "bar"}) 

const fooBarHash = hash({foo: "foo", bar: "bar"})
```

Is there a `combine` function, such that:

```
combine(fooHash, barHash) === fooBarHash
```

?

If yes, how would the `combine` function work?

Comment: By combine you probably mean `$.extend(obj1,obj2)`?

Comment: Note that OP is asking for a function that reads "string hashes".

Comment: The combine function I am searching for should operate on the hashes, not on the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hashing function is reversible, then you can have the following combine function:

```
function combine(obj1hash, obj2hash) {
  return hash(merge(unhash(obj1hash), unhash(obj2hash)));
}
```

`hash` and `unhash` can be `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. `merge` is any function that merges two js objects like [this one](https://plainjs.com/javascript/utilities/merge-two-javascript-objects-19/).

Comment: if it's not possible to reverse the action, it's not doable. On the other hand, you can get away without converting back to POJO.

Comment: That would work, but `JSON.stringify` will break on cyclical objects. Also, I didn't say so, but by hashes, I intended "fixed-size string hashes". For my use case, I need to avoid serializing the entire object, because I want to quickly compare a lot of objects.
 I'll update my question accordingly :)

Comment: Yeah I thought about that. As mentioned it's probably not possible. This is a cryptography-related question and not a javascript one.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that it is impossible without a reversible hashing function?

Comment: I'm not an expert in cryptography, but I'd say 90% yes it's not possible.

Comment: You might want to ask the question in http://crypto.stackexchange.com/. Just treat the js object as a json string and it becomes a mathematical challenge.

Comment: @anatol Let me suggest something else. What you need is a function `contains(hash(obj1), hash(parent))` which returns true when `parent` is contained within `obj1`. This might have a better chance of finding a solution.

Comment: heh, never thought about that! Ill let it brew a little here (dont want to spam) but I'll definitely repost it there if there will be no answers here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98489/discussion-between-anatol-and-louy).